# Android: AdWhirl cannot find AdMobAdapter

Tags: android, admob, ads-api, adwhirl

Using AdMob by itself works perfectly. Using AdMob through AdWhirl causes the following problem:

```
 23114               dalvikvm  I  Failed resolving Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/AdMobAdapter; interface 144 'Lcom/admob/android/ads/AdListener;'                                                     
 23114               dalvikvm  W  Link of class 'Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/AdMobAdapter;' failed                                                                                                  
 23114               dalvikvm  E  Could not find class 'com.adwhirl.adapters.AdMobAdapter', referenced from method com.adwhirl.adapters.AdWhirlAdapter.getAdapter                             
 23114               dalvikvm  W  VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 172 (Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/AdMobAdapter;) in Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/AdWhirlAdapter;                                      
 23114               dalvikvm  D  VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0012                                                                                                                        
 23114               dalvikvm  D  Making a copy of Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/AdWhirlAdapter;.getAdapter code (229 bytes)                                                                          
 23114               dalvikvm  I  Failed resolving Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/QuattroAdapter; interface 524 'Lcom/qwapi/adclient/android/view/AdEventsListener;'                                   
 23114               dalvikvm  W  Link of class 'Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/QuattroAdapter;' failed                                                                                                
 23114               dalvikvm  E  Could not find class 'com.adwhirl.adapters.QuattroAdapter', referenced from method com.adwhirl.adapters.AdWhirlAdapter.getAdapter                           
 23114               dalvikvm  W  VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 177 (Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/QuattroAdapter;) in Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/AdWhirlAdapter;                                    
 23114               dalvikvm  D  VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x002c                                                                                                                        
 23114         AndroidRuntime  D  Shutting down VM                                                                                                                                            
 23114               dalvikvm  W  threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b180)                                                                                       
 23114            FlurryAgent  D  Ending session                                                                                                                                              
 23114        LocationManager  D  removeUpdates: listener = com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent@4496be70                                                                                           
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E  Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception                                                                                             
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.adwhirl.adapters.AdMobAdapter                                                                                           
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at com.adwhirl.adapters.AdWhirlAdapter.getAdapter(AdWhirlAdapter.java:39)                                                                             
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.handleAd(AdWhirlLayout.java:154)                                                                                         
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.access$0(AdWhirlLayout.java:143)                                                                                         
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$1.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:87)                                                                                             
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)                                                                                                
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)                                                                                                
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)                                                                                                            
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)                                                                                          
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                                               
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)                                                                                                   
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)                                                                    
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)                                                                                       
 23114         AndroidRuntime  E        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use adwhirl you still have to include all the other ad sdks.  Looks like it can't find

```
com/admob/android/ads/AdListener
Lcom/qwapi/adclient/android/view/AdEventsListener
```

Make sure you are still including the admob and quattro sdks.

Comment: They are included, but I found out, that AdWhirl doesn't work with the latest AdMob SDK, because of some changes they made there.

Comment: I know this is old, but you might want to check out MoPub.